# HMRC have given SLC wrong repayment details after job change

Tags: united-kingdom, student-loan

I have a plan 1 Income Contingent Loan from the Student Loans Company.

I started a new job at the start of this year. My new employer took a copy of the appropriate part of my P45.
I am on PAYE for both jobs.

Reading my payslips from April 2018 (inc) to December 2018 I paid £799 in student loan deductions.
From Jan 2019 - Mar 2019 (with my new employer) I paid £801 in student loan dedications.

I have had a statement from the Student Loads Company which says, based on the repayment information from HMRC, the total repayments received 6/4/18 - 5/4/19 was £801.

It looks like the other £799 I paid at my old employer have been missed.
How do I get this corrected?

I am coming towards the end of my repayments and would like to get this right

On checking my P60 issued by my new employer (for tax year ending Apr 2019) the student load deductions (in this employment) is marked at £801, (which is correct, for this employment, but doesn't details previous employment)

Comment: You have your documentation, which should be sent either to HMRC or SLC (or even both). Unfortunately although the action is obvious, who you should actually send copies to is not, to me at least. Perhaps it will be to someone else. (I suspect it's HMRC though, since they send the information to SLC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I phoned SLC, they explained they now get regular updates from HMRC (but it sounds like they are not processed when received).

The advisor checked and found a more recent update from HMRC which included my missing payments, from this he was able to recalculate my balance and advise me how to proceed from here.

So the answer is phone SLC and get them to check for HMRC updates.